# create color box on the background of text in html

Tags: html

I am creating the following webpage using html. In the "Your indicators" section, there are red and purple rectangles that are placed below the white color text.

[image]

I used the following in my style section

```
  span.leftrange{
    background:red;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    width:auto;
  }
  span.rightrange{
    background:purple;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    text-align:center
  }
```

And in the actual text and radio button, I use:

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Indicators</legend>
    <label for="height">Height:</label>
    <span class="leftrange">Short</span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" id="height" name="height">
    <span class="rightrange">Tall</span>
    <br>

    <label for="height">Salary:</label>
    <span class="leftrange">Poor</span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="50" id="salary" name="salary">
    <span class="rightrange">Rich</span>
    <br>
    </fieldset>
```

My solution have two things that are different from the pic:

1.I want the texts to align in the center. But Short and Poor in my solution are left aligned. Tall and Rich are right aligned.

2.I want the two rectangle with the same size and also have some margin on the left and right side of the text. But my background rectangle size is only big enough to wrap around the text, i.e., the red rectangle for short is bigger than the one for poor.

How to resolve these two differences? All code should be in html.

Comment: Any other people can answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

can you please add padding left and top in leftrange class. padding-top bottom n right to rightrange class. Although you have text-align centre. It should be given padding.

```
span.leftrange{
background:red;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
text-align:center;
width:auto;
padding-top:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
width:100px;
width:100px;
float:centre;

}
span.rightrange{
background:purple;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding-top:10px;
padding-right:10px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
width:100px;
width:100px;
float:centre;

}
```

Comment: hmm, you solution does give flexibility to adjust the size of the background rectangle. However, it does not solve either of my problem.

Comment: do you want text at centre of reactangle?

Comment: yes. rectangle size also should not change based on the size of text as I explained in 1 and 2.

Comment: yes then we have to hardcode width and height of rectangle otherwise it will adjust according to text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118754/discussion-between-akash-bhandwalkar-and-elixir).

Comment: I think the requirement is quite clear. I will wait for the solution.